# XAMPP 7.4.23 Developer Package

Tags: xampp, fedora

I wanted to install an extension on Xampp.. I execute phpize by running something like: /opt/lampp/bin/phpize.. and boooom! I start getting some xampp error messages as shown below:

***grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory***

****grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory****

***grep: /opt/lampp/include/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory***

I was researching on the internet and found that the solution involved installing the XAMPP development package, but I can't find this package for the version I have installed: 7.4.23.

My system is LINUX running FEDORA 39.
Thank you

Comment: So is it Xampp (windows) or Lampp (linux)? Can you specify exact command that you have run instead of "something like"?

Comment: Hello, 
It is LAMPP and the comand is exactly: /opt/lampp/bin/phpize.

Answer (score -1):

My mistake! The XAMPP development package files were available as an option in the installation program, and when I installed it, I chose not to install them. Anyway, a silly mistake!

Comment: Please just delete your question as it does not bring any useful information for future readers